# How Can I Turn A MonthYear String Into A Datetime Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I currently have a string in the format of month year. The month is 3 characters long and the year is 4. Below are some examples of some of the dates that I have.

```
apr2021
jun2021
mar2020
dec2020
```

I have a date in a pandas dataframe that is in the form of yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. I want to compare this string to the date in pandas and determine if it is less than or equal to it? Is there a way to turn this month-year string into an actual date format?

I'm going to strip the date to yyyy-mm-dd and then try to get the month-year string in the same format and then do a direct comparison. I'm not quite sure if there is a more efficient way to do this though?

Example pseudo-code below:

```
temp_date = apr2021 -> 01-04-2021
pandas_date = 29-03-2021

if temp_date < pandas_date:
    do x
else:
    do y
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert your dates, both in your dataframe and for an isolated string. Then you will be able to perform comparisons using `>`/`<` or the pandas methods `gt`/`lt`/…:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'temp_date': ['apr2021', 'jun2021', 'mar2020', 'dec2020']})
df['temp_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['temp_date'])

pandas_date = pd.to_datetime('29-03-2021') # optional

import numpy as np

df['new_col'] = np.where(df['temp_date'].gt(pandas_date), 'greater', 'lower')
```

output:

```
   temp_date  new_col
0 2021-04-01  greater
1 2021-06-01  greater
2 2020-03-01    lower
3 2020-12-01    lower
```

*NB. following up on the comment, there is a full list of datetime formats in [`datetime`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), in your case this would be `%b%Y`: `pd.to_datetime('apr2021', format='%b%Y')`*

Comment: Thank you! I had no clue to_datetime would work on strings like that since it seems like it's in a non-standard format. This is definitely what I needed. Thanks again!

Comment: Even if you have a non standard format you can pass the format using `format="…"`, check the documentation linked in my answer ;) In your case this would be `pd.to_datetime('apr2021', format='%b%Y')`

Answer (score 3):

`pd.to_datetime` is what you're looking for.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.to_datetime("apr2021")
Timestamp('2021-04-01 00:00:00')
```